# How to configure Redis inbound channel adaptor in Spring integration DSL?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-integration, spring-data-redis, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to set up a caching service using Spring boot/integration. This service has to retrieve data from Redis database every 6 minutes. I have followed this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/redis.html#redis-outbound-channel-adapter) and there is no example for Spring integration DSL.

```
<int-redis:inbound-channel-adapter id="redisAdapter"
   topics="thing1, thing2"
   channel="receiveChannel"
   error-channel="testErrorChannel"
   message-converter="testConverter" />
```

I have also followed the example mentioned in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407160/create-messagesource-for-redis-in-spring-integration) page.

```
@Bean
RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory, RedisSerializer<?> serializer) {
    RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint =
                new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint("archive.post.publication.queue", redisConnectionFactory);
    endpoint.setOutputChannelName("postPublicationChannel");
    endpoint.setErrorChannelName("postPublicationLoggingChannel");
    endpoint.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
    endpoint.setSerializer(serializer);
    return endpoint;
}
```

I have tried examples from various documentation and none of them related to my scenario. Any help is much appreciated?